# Unexpected response code 500 com.android.volley.ServerError

Tags: android, laravel, rest, web-services, android-volley

I am trying to sign up users from mobile application. My web service is working on localhost and i am able to register users from Postman but when i try to post a request from mobile app using volley it give unexpected response code error.
While GET requests are working fine.

Comment: so, in your api side request accepted by only GET

Comment: And have you looked in the Laravel logs?

Comment: @Sanjay from android application only get requests are working fine while from Postman both get and post are working

Comment: can we show your code?

Comment: @ka_lin no i have not looked in the laravel logs as i am not good in laravel but my web service is working fine in postman.

Comment: @Sanjay here it is

Comment: StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url", new Response.Listener<String>() {
       
            public void onResponse(String response) {


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
   
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        })

        {

Comment: my machine IP is 172.19.130.35 as web service is running on localhost

Comment: have pass parameter?

Comment: yes  @Sanjay
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("name","Nouman");
                map.put("email","nouman.jamil@outlook.com");
                map.put("password","111");
                map.put("c_password","111");
                return map;
            }

Comment: @Sanjay  headers portion public Map<String, String> getHeaders()  {
                HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");
                return map;
            }

Comment: i think problem with your localhost url

Comment: @Sanjay from same localhost url my get requests are working fine